# bundle exec rake assets:precompile issue with the generated application.js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, web-deployment

I could successfully host the [fulcrum app](https://github.com/malclocke/fulcrum) on phusion but I am going nuts with some configuration issue

The application is picking up the url as

```
http://example.com/projects/4
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/fulcrum/projects/4
```

Could anyone point the mistake. I tried to change the assets.prefix in production.rb and recompile the assets but it only changes the location of the assets but doesn't change the root url in application.js

THe app is hosted at

```
http://example.com/fulcrum
```

And the rest of the site is functional except for this jquery/ajax part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://example.com/fulcrum"`in your production.rb should do the trick.

If you're sending emails you should set `config.action_mailer.asset_host` too.